# Merging WebSphere Application Server into WebSphere ESB installation

Tags: websphere, esb

I have an architecture where I have one machine with a Websphere Application Server an another one with an Websphere EBS.

The workload is pretty low, so one single machine (as I have now) would be enough. According to this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wsesb/v6/faqs.html#notify),

> Because WebSphere ESB is built on WebSphere Application Server,
>   through their WebSphere ESB license; customers are able to utilize
>   WebSphere Application Server function.

So, WAS functionality is available in the Websphere ESB. 
Is it possible to merge/combine/integrate the code from WAS into the WESB in order to have one license and one server only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can and it is fairly simple too.

Install WESB and create WESB Profiles and deployed Mediation modules in them and create WAS Profiles and host standard Java EE applications on these profiles.

WESB versions uses typically a older version of WAS so you might have to think through this restriction before proceeding in this path.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy applications targeted to WAS on WESB without any trouble. The other way round would be risky, though not impossible.

As Manglu said, you'll need to be careful about versions and, if this is for production, you'll need to be aware of what fixes you have installed and make sure your target server is at the same, or higher level than the current WAS installation.

To find this out, use the versionInfo command with the option -maintenancePackages and you'll get a list of the levels of each component and any APARs installed.

Instructions are here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21267921

> **Windows**
>
> versionInfo.bat -maintenanacePackages >versioninfo.txt
>
> **AIX, HP-UX, Linux, Solaris**
>
> ./versionInfo.sh -maintenanacePackages >versioninfo.txt